How do I get past "Problem Removing toplevel directory
I am trying to package things using CPack and attacehd is my cpack file. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing to get this pushed past this point. I have had it stuck on this even when using -D CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY=1 and 0.
CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY=1 and 0 to have an impact of sorts. I've also tried to make this into a package via following the build/ make install commands. I tried finding a defualt value and trying a more basic package but it's confused me greatly.
# This file will be configured to contain variables for CPack. These variables
# should be set in the CMake list file of the project before CPack module is
# included. The list of available CPACK_xxx variables and their associated
# documentation may be obtained using
#  cpack --help-variable-list
#
# Some variables are common to all generators (e.g. CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME)
# and some are specific to a generator
# (e.g. CPACK_NSIS_EXTRA_INSTALL_COMMANDS). The generator specific variables
# usually begin with CPACK_<GENNAME>_xxxx.

set(CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY "1")
set(CPACK_BUILD_SOURCE_DIRS ";")
set(CPACK_CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles")
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL "")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_UNSPECIFIED_HIDDEN "TRUE")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_UNSPECIFIED_REQUIRED "TRUE")
set(CPACK_DEFAULT_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "/usr/share/cmake/Templates/CPack.GenericDescription.txt")
set(CPACK_DEFAULT_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY " built using CMake")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "RPM")
set(CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR};${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME};ALL;/")
# set(CPACK_INSTALL_CMAKE_PROJECTS "libmodbus-3.0.8.tar;ALL;ALL;/")
set(CPACK_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
set(CPACK_MODULE_PATH "")
set(CPACK_NSIS_DISPLAY_NAME "libmodbus-3.0.8")
set(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALLER_ICON_CODE "")
set(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALLER_MUI_ICON_CODE "")
set(CPACK_NSIS_INSTALL_ROOT "$PROGRAMFILES")
set(CPACK_NSIS_PACKAGE_NAME "libmodbus-3.0.8")
set(CPACK_NSIS_UNINSTALL_NAME "Uninstall")
set(CPACK_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE "/CPackConfig.cmake")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "Mark Doellman")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DEFAULT_LOCATION "/")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_FILE "/usr/share/cmake/Templates/CPack.GenericDescription.txt")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY " built using CMake")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "libmodbus-3.0.8-x86_64")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "libmodbus-3.0.8")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY "libmodbus-3.0.8")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "libmodbus-3.0.8")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_RELOCATABLE "true")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "GE Aerospace")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "3.0.8")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr/local")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_LICENSE "/usr/share/cmake/Templates/CPack.GenericLicense.txt")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_README "/usr/share/cmake/Templates/CPack.GenericDescription.txt")
set(CPACK_RESOURCE_FILE_WELCOME "/usr/share/cmake/Templates/CPack.GenericWelcome.txt")
set(CPACK_RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE "1")
set(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR "OFF")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "TBZ2;TGZ;TXZ;TZ")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE "/CPackSourceConfig.cmake")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_RPM "OFF")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_TBZ2 "ON")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_TGZ "ON")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_TXZ "ON")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_TZ "ON")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_ZIP "OFF")
set(CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME "Linux")
set(CPACK_THREADS "1")
set(CPACK_TOPLEVEL_TAG "Linux")
set(CPACK_WIX_SIZEOF_VOID_P "")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY "1")

if(NOT CPACK_PROPERTIES_FILE)
  set(CPACK_PROPERTIES_FILE "/CPackProperties.cmake")
endif()

if(EXISTS ${CPACK_PROPERTIES_FILE})
  include(${CPACK_PROPERTIES_FILE})
endif()

 cpack --verbose --config default.cmake -D CPACK_INCLUDE_TOPLEVEL_DIRECTORY=0
CPack: Enable Verbose
CPack Verbose: Read CPack config file: default.cmake
CPack Verbose: Read CPack configuration file: /mnt/c/Users/503373880/Documents/Projects/RHEL-Packages/TSDS/libmodbus-3.0.8.tar/default.cmake
CPack Verbose: Specified generator: RPM
CPack Verbose: Use generator: cmCPackRPMGenerator
CPack Verbose: For project: libmodbus-3.0.8
CPack: Create package using RPM
CPack Verbose: Read description file: /usr/share/cmake/Templates/CPack.GenericDescription.txt
CPack Verbose: [RPM] requested component grouping = ONE_PER_GROUP
CPack Verbose: Remove toplevel directory: /mnt/c/Users/503373880/Documents/Projects/RHEL-Packages/TSDS/libmodbus-3.0.8.tar/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM
CPack Error: Problem removing toplevel directory: /mnt/c/Users/503373880/Documents/Projects/RHEL-Packages/TSDS/libmodbus-3.0.8.tar/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM
CPack Error: Error when generating package: libmodbus-3.0.8

This is the contents of my .cmake file
My issue is that the package won't build due to it being stuck on "CPack Error: Problem removing toplevel directory:" No matter what have changed, or adding the flags to ignore or accept it.

Please, [edit] your question post and elaborate "Problem Removing toplevel directory". In the current form of the post it is unclear what is your problem.

@Tsyvarev I uploaded the screenshot of the command and also added the reason at the bottom. Thank you!

No, do not use images for represent textual information. Instead, paste the error message directly into the question post as text. See also that question on meta.

I missed that! I went ahead and added it as a code block instead! I appreciate the guidance.
